# I want to upgrade my GTX 580 to something that could handle 2 4k screens. Can I do that?

Tags: graphics-cards, gaming, 4k

I have one DELL 3415W right now as my off screen (which the graphics card lower framerate on to 30hz or something to be able to use it) and an old 1920x1080 screen which it can only run as high as 60hz (this is what I want to change to another 4k... maybe the same as my off screen). I think my power supply is big (1KW).

I run windows 10 on an Intel Core i7 CPU X 990 3.47GHz with two SCSI disc (256GB SSD + 1.8TB HD). I wan't to upgrade my GTX 580 graphics card so it can handle 2 4k screens at the same time, but can I do this?

If yes, what would be a good choice? I am a hardware noob so let me know if anything else is needed to answer the question.

Comment: You don't mention a budget nor physical card size limitations. Also how are you planning to use the 2 4K displays, gaming or work or what?

Comment: Since you are using the gaming tag, what games do you play? Do you use any graphics intensive software?

Comment: I have a big computer case so i dont think there are any special size restrictions. I want to be able to drive one 4k screen for gaming (only playing Destiny 2 right now, but I don't want to limit myself), and I want to use one 4k screen for non-gaming things. Of course I want to limit the amount of money I spend but that is not my primary concern since I tend to buy expensive but very seldom :)

Comment: Volta and Navi, the next generation of GPUs, are both going to be released early next year,  on a 12 nm shrink, so if you can wait a bit, there's should be enough extra performance to be worth it.